# How to locate places nearby to my custom markers

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a webapp that creates markers on a google map and I'm wondering if there is some way to locate place nearby my custom markers so users can see what is around them.

Thank you in advance,

Robert

Comment: Do you have a datastore of these places around your markers? What kind of things do you want to show?

Comment: I want to show any restaurants, hotels, bars/clubs, or Stores nearby so people can get an idea of where they are looking at without having to zoom in and look at street names and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Places Library**[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlacesService) provides the information you seek. You load the library by adding the `libraries=places` parameter to the URL that loads the Google Map, as shown here:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false">
</script>
```

And then you request data about places using code similar to this, copied from the [**Place Search Requests** section of the Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests), which will search for stores within 500 meters of the point defined in the variable `pyrmont`:

```
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: pyrmont,
      zoom: 15
    });

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '500',
    types: ['store']
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.search(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}
```